# What arithmetic operations are supported by CQL?

Tags: cassandra

Are the trivial arithmetic operations as sum (+), subtraction (-), division (/), multiplication (*) supported in the SELECT part of the Cassandra CQL query?

Comment: I don't see a reference to math operations of any kind in the [Cassandra CQL Documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html).

Comment: Me neither thus asking. Seems only the COUNT function is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT` is the only one so far but this is because cql is still maturing to a full feature language. You could request the implementation of arithmetic operations ([through Apache C* Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3asummary-panel)) but I think that CQL solutions let the application handle such simple things.

Comment: What CSQL solutions I am curious let handle that?

Comment: I have added a request to add such a capability https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5505